# Importing postman into Paw doesn't work

Tags: paw-app

I exported a postman file as described on Paw extension and then imported using the postman importer. I see the imported group in Paw but the calls are all missing.

{"id":"476dc4a4-6a1e-02fd-93e8-fe82108caa2d","name":"ACME","timestamp":1428427257940,"requests":[{"collectionId":"476dc4a4-6a1e-02fd-93e8-fe82108caa2d","id":"00229e57-d36b-4589-9108-9491a434ef37","name":"token","description":"","url":"http://mydomain/rest/v10/oauth2/token","method":"POST","headers":"","data":"{\n   \"grant_type\":\"password\",\n   \"client_id\":\"sugar\",\n   \"client_secret\":\"\",\n   \"username\":\"XXX\",\n   \"password\":\"XXX\",\n   \"platform\":\"webservice\"\n}","dataMode":"raw","timestamp":0,"responses":[],"version":2}]}

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Paw's documentation has been updated, and there's a new article on [How to migrate from Postman to Paw](https://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/migrate/postman)

---

This was a bug in the [Postman Importer](https://github.com/luckymarmot/Paw-PostmanImporter) [v1.0.0](https://github.com/luckymarmot/Paw-PostmanImporter/releases/tag/v1.0.0). I've just fixed that bug in [v1.0.1](https://github.com/luckymarmot/Paw-PostmanImporter/releases/tag/v1.0.1). It happened because for some reason there are Postman Collections that are missing the "order" field (to keep the order of requests in the collection) the importer was expecting.

Anyways, it's now fixed. Please update your Extension in Paw menu Paw > Extensions > Check for Extensions Updates.

Hope it helps!